# Installing ubuntu in Lenovo y50-70: using the nvidia graphic card

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried to follow this post to [Switch Between Intel and Nvidia Graphics Card in Ubuntu 16.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/) but i cant make it working. When i run `nvidia-settings` the prime profiles do not exist as an option in the nvidia x server settings. Furthermore in the terminal the following message appears:

[image]

Furthermore, When I run `sudo lshw -C display` i got the following:

[image]

Why in the nvidia graphic card its showed as `display UNCLAIMED`?

Also I run `lspci| grep -i vga` where it shows only the INtel corporation 4th gen core processor graphic controller and not the nvidia graphic card. THe nvidia graphic card is only displayed in `lspci| grep -i 3d`.

Any advice how to make it work?

**Edit:** Somehow the display is not Unclaimed anymore. Cant reproduce how I did that because I tried many different things. But this did not solve the problem.

**Edit2:** The drivers that are installed `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`:

[image]

Comment: What driver version have you installed? The guide you followed has many mistakes. One is a fundamental misunderstanding of `nvidia-current` which installs 340, the current long time support stable driver, not the latest current version. The second is the silliness of opening Additional drivers, then terminal then AD again... The point is still what driver version have you installed? Versions from 361 to 378 should work. (And you need to disable secure boot)

Comment: Everything I commented above you can read in users' comments in the link you gave.

Comment: From my understand both 367 and 340 are installed. I have updated my question with output of the drivers installed.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` gives information about what's available, not what's installed. 367 should work with your graphics. Open Additional drivers and make sure to select and apply the highest version offered if not select and in use already.